# Assignment vs Initialization in C++

Tags: c++, class, initialization, operator-overloading

I thought that constructors control initialization and operator= functions control assignment in C++. So why does this code work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Deg {
    public:
        Deg() {}
        Deg(int a) : d(a) {}        
        void operator()(double a)
        {
            cout << pow(a,d) << endl;
        }

    private:
        int d;
};

int
main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    Deg d = 2;
    d(5);
    d = 3; /* this shouldn't work, Deg doesn't have an operator= that takes an int */
    d(5);
    return 0;
}
```

On the third line of the main function, I am assigning an `int` to an object of class `Deg`. Since I don't have an `operator=(int)` function, I thought that this would certainly fail...but instead it calls the `Deg(int a)` constructor. So do constructors control assignment as well?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what's called implicit type conversion. The compiler will look to see if there's a constructor to directly change from the type you're assigning to the type you're trying to assign, and call it. You can stop it from happening by adding the `explicit` keyword in front of the constructor you wouldn't like to be implicitly called, like this:

`explicit Deg(int a) : d(a) {}`

Comment: At least one company I've worked at has had the rule "use explicit on all constructors unless there's a good reason not to" among its coding standards.  That helps avoid potentially puzzling situations like this.

Comment: I suppose you mean on all constructors that can be invoked with a single argument :) ?

Comment: "A good reason not to [use explicit]" would be needless confusion when used on multi-arg ctors.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify JonM's answer:

For the line `d = 3`, an assignment operator **is** involved.  `3` is being implicitly converted to a `Deg`, as JonM said, and then that `Deg` is **assigned** to `d` using the compiler-generated assignment operator (which by default does a member-wise assignment).  If you want to prevent assignment, you must declare a private assignment operator (and do not implement it):

```
//...
private:
    Deg& operator=(const Deg&);
}
```